# Pulling XCOM when creating a dataproc cluster with DataprocCreateClusterOperator in airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to pull an XCOM variable when creating a dataproc cluster in airflow with DataprocCreateClusterOperator. I need it because I need a variable that I am pulling by querying an API and saving as XCOM variable in the preceding step.

What I'm trying to do:

```
build_dataproc_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
        task_id="create_cluster",
        retries=3,
        project_id=project_id,
        region=region,
        cluster_name=cluster_name,
        cluster_config=ClusterGenerator(
        num_workers=cluster_node_count,
        ...
           properties={
               "spark-env:ENCRYPT_KEY":{{ kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_task', key='my_secret_key') }}
           }
       ).make()
)
```

Not surprisingly, this throws me the error that kwargs is not defined. But I'm not sure if there's a way I can pull a value from XCOM when defining a DataprocCreateClusterOperator task? Do I need to define a new class that would extend "DataprocCreateClusterOperator" or is there some easier way?

Tried a few other options like querying the API before executing the DAG. The thing is I want to only query that API when I execute the dag, and not when airflow refreshes it.

Comment: cluster_config is in the template_field so it should supprt jinja template. replace kwargs[ti] with ti (remove the kwargs)